# PySpark: How do I replace Null values based on Datatype of the column?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a table, which contains 257 columns. I am trying to figure out how to change null values which are in the table based on the data type. I am trying to do this in PySpark. And the dataframe name is called df.

So for example, if a column contains a date it's a timestamp data type and the nulls within that column need to be 1900-01-01

If it is any integer or float type it needs to be a 0

If it's a string type it should be a n/a

Thank you

Comment: do you just want to set the default values for certain columns? What does the data type have to do with this? Column nullability, default values, and data type are all part of the schema, which ideally you would define in advance.

Comment: For int and string types, try this `df = df.na.fill(0).na.fill('na')` but not sure about the timestamp. Maybe convert it to string and follow the same.

Comment: The reason is the data I am getting is in a temp view from SQL, I am converting that into a pyspark df so I can loop through all the columns. As for why datatypes are important, the original list contains a number of different datatypes, and different datatypes require different null values.. for example as said above if it is a null value in an integer column, the null value needs to be zero, but if it is a null value in a datetime column it needs to be 1900-01-01. So I am trying to figure out how to automate the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.dtypes` will give you a declaration of each column. Something like this:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('str', '2022-01-01', 1, 2.2, False),
    (None, None, None, None, None),
], ['text','date','int','float', 'bool'])
df = df.withColumn('date', F.col('date').cast('date'))
df.show()
df.printSchema()
print(df.dtypes)

+----+----------+----+-----+-----+
|text|      date| int|float| bool|
+----+----------+----+-----+-----+
| str|2022-01-01|   1|  2.2|false|
|null|      null|null| null| null|
+----+----------+----+-----+-----+

root
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- int: long (nullable = true)
 |-- float: double (nullable = true)
 |-- bool: boolean (nullable = true)

[('text', 'string'),
 ('date', 'date'),
 ('int', 'bigint'),
 ('float', 'double'),
 ('bool', 'boolean')]
```

With this information, you can dynamically cast any default value you want depends on its types

```py
for t in df.dtypes:
    if t[1] == 'string':
        df = df.withColumn(t[0], F.coalesce(t[0], F.lit('n/a')))
    elif t[1] == 'date':
        df = df.withColumn(t[0], F.coalesce(t[0], F.lit('1900-01-01')))
    elif t[1] == 'boolean':
        df = df.withColumn(t[0], F.coalesce(t[0], F.lit(False)))
    else:
        df = df.withColumn(t[0], F.coalesce(t[0], F.lit(0)))
    
df.show()

+----+----------+---+-----+-----+
|text|      date|int|float| bool|
+----+----------+---+-----+-----+
| str|2022-01-01|  1|  2.2|false|
| n/a|1900-01-01|  0|  0.0|false|
+----+----------+---+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it helps, to close the thread :)

Comment: @pltc, what is F in F.coalesce- does it need to be declared as variable or is it alias of any package that needs to be imported?